# how to implement the following layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, accordion, android-scrollview

[image]

Hello all

I need to implement this layout 
I have the following problem and need an advice

the all screen should be scrollable 
the data model is like the following

List of groups each group contains (title and subtitle and a list of items)

the item contains (icon, title, price, help text)

the first item should be by default shown and a view all text

when user press view all all other items should be expanded and the view should be also expanded and keep the scrolling on the all view

I need to use scrollview as parent, but can not add inside it listview because it will not work, also the listview itself should be expandable to view other items in the group

can any one please advice if there is any thing that can be done to achieve this UI layout.

Comment: This is far too broad. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view completely suits here. It's will a bit complicated, but it definitely right way

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ScrollView` and one `ConstraintLayout` inside of it 
and inside that put a `RecycleView` inside it after that is simple view in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView with Footer.
like,
Footer means that view which is only use one time in footer.
You can add footer view after last position.
here your footer view is that which is show in  bottom.